# Spark scala RDD traversing

Tags: scala, dictionary, apache-spark, rdd

How can i traverse following RDD using Spark scala. I wants to print every value present in Seq with associated key

```
res1: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(java.lang.String, Seq[java.lang.String])] = MapPartitionsRDD[6] at groupByKey at <console>:14
```

I tried following code for it.

```
val ss=mapfile.map(x=>{  
val key=x._1
val value=x._2.sorted
  var i=0
 while (i < value.length) {
   (key,value(i))
    i += 1
      }
    }     
  )
ss.top(20).foreach(println)
```

Answer (score 3):

I try to convert your codes as follows:

```
val ss = mapfile.flatMap { 
  case (key, value) => value.sorted.map((key, _))
}
ss.top(20).foreach(println)
```

Is it what you want?

Comment: @samthebest Style edits like yours where the original formatting was *absolutely fine* are generally frowned upon: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/263115/when-is-it-okay-to-edit-answers-for-code-formatting/263121#263121

Comment: @LimbSoup my changes where "clearly and objectively better". Intellij would have performed the formatting changes, i.e. added a space and a new line.  Perhaps it is the removal of an unnecessary parameter value name in the lambda that you think is 'personal preference', however I would argue this is a general programming principle; KISS, don't name things that don't need names - why bloat code?!

Comment: @samthebest "Clearly and objectively better" means that the code had no formatting to begin with. Citing what Intellij would do isn't valid. Not everyone writes that way. The linked post on Meta **clearly** states that moving braces onto new lines to "correct" formatting is frowned upon. As for the difference between named values and underscores, that is also a personal preference. What you think is bloated someone else might prefer.

Comment: @LimbSoup Intellij default style settings follow the style guide exactly, which says "function values ... The declaration itself should loosely follow the declaration style for methods, with the opening brace on the same line as the assignment or invocation, while the closing brace is on its own line immediately following the last line of the function." http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/declarations.html  Finally to think omitting the space before the curly brace is acceptable is nearly as ridiculous as saying there should be no spaces between operators!

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it works for the return type as mentioned.

```
val ss=mapfile.map(x=>{case (key, value) => value.sorted.map((key, _))}.groupByKey().map(x=>(x._1,x._2.toSeq))

    ss.top(20).foreach(println)
```

Note: ss is of type:::   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(java.lang.String, Seq[java.lang.String])]